# C++, How to create and draw a Binary Tree then traverse it in Pre-Order

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

How do I create a Binary Tree and draw it using a Pre-Order Traversal strategy?  The root would be the first number going in.

I have a set of numbers: `48 32 51 54 31 24 39`.  48 would be the root.  How are the child nodes pushed onto the Binary Tree in a Pre-Order traversal?

Comment: Are you trying to construct a binary tree given a pre-order traversal? Or are you trying to get the pre-order travel on a binary tree? (sorry, the question is not very clear)

Comment: what are the numbers that would result from a PRe-Order Traversal of the binary tree built using the above numberrs

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the following sub-problem. You have a set of numbers:

```
N A1...AX B1...BY
```

You know that `N` is the root of the corresponding tree. All you need to know is what numbers form the left sub-tree. Obviously the rest of the numbers form the right sub-tree.

If you remember the properties of a binary-search trees, you would know that elements of the left sub-tree have values smaller than the root (while the ones on the right have values bigger).

Therefore, the left sub-tree is the sequence of numbers that are smaller than (or possibly equal to) `N`. The rest of the numbers are in the right sub-tree.

Recursively solve for

```
A1...AX
```

and

```
B1...BY
```

For example given:

```
10 1 5 2 9 3 1 6 4 11 15 12 19 20
```

You get:

- root: 10
- left sub-tree: 1 5 2 9 3 1 6 4
- right sub-tree: 11 15 12 19 20

Comment: Ok, maybe it's just me but I can't pinpoint this. Ill give you an array of intergers: 47 43 20 24 32 44 35. So the tree would be: 47 left sub-tree: 20 24 32 right sub-tree: 44,43,35?

Comment: No, 44, 43 and 35 are all smaller than 47. This means that 47 is the root, left sub-tree contains all the 6 numbers and the right sub-tree is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have the following binary tree:

```
        A
      /    \  
    B        C   
   / \      / \
  D   E    F   G
     / \    
    H   I
```

A Pre-Order Traversal goes NODE, LEFT, RIGHT.

So Pre-Order of this binary tree would be: `A B D E H I C F G`

For more details on how to implement this in C++:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658699/445131